# Are there any "gum wall" tourist attractions outside the US?

Tags: where-on-earth, tourist-traps

I am aware of two "gum wall" tourist attractions in the US, in [Seattle, WA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gum_Wall) and [San Luis Obispo, California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubblegum_Alley).

Are there any "gum wall" tourist attractions outside the US?

---

My research:

- I've googled "gum wall" and don't see it any "gum wall" tourist attractions outside the US:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL6UW.jpg
- I've googled "Are there any "gum wall" tourist attractions outside the US?"  and don't see it any "gum wall" tourist attractions outside the US:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkUzh.jpg

---

Gum wall in Seattle:

[image]

(Image author: [Diego Delso](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Poco_a_poco), license: [CC BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/))

Comment: Have you tried google? Because that easily shows another gum wall.

Comment: This style of question doesn't really fit the SE Question and Answer model. You're either expecting a Yes/No answer, or a list of answers. See [Are list questions off topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139618/are-list-questions-off-topic)

Comment: @PeterM I've googled "gum wall"  and don't see it easily. Could you please share the name? Maybe because since I am in the US, the results I see on Google are biased toward the US.

Comment: @Midavalo thanks, Yes/No are ok on SE. As for list questions, some SE specialize in lists, eg the software recommendation Stack Exchange.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt So you would be happy with an answer that just said "Yes"?

Comment: @Midavalo would be better if it came with some evidence, ie an example

Comment: @PeterM Thanks, do you prefer post it as answer or shall I do it? I didn't think of adding that particular keyword as I haven't been there for many years.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I agree with Midvalo's assessment of this question and IMHO it should be closed/removed for those reasons.

Comment: Always amazed by questions which could have been answered in literally less than 5 seconds with Google

Comment: @eps I've googled "gum wall" and didn't see it easily. Do you? Adding the location of the gum wall in the query is pretty much assuming one knows the answer when looking for it.

Comment: Like quite literally just plop "Are there any "gum wall" tourist attractions outside the US?" in google lol

Comment: @Eps shows US gum wall on my side. Send screenshot. since I am in the US, the results I see on Google are biased toward the US.

Comment: @eps - I've googled "gum wall" and don't see it any "gum wall" tourist attractions outside the US:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/fL6UW.jpg
- I've googled "Are there any "gum wall" tourist attractions outside the US?"  and don't see it any "gum wall" tourist attractions outside the US:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkUzh.jpg. Please show your screenshot.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> Are there any "gum wall" tourist attractions outside the US?

Yes, e.g. part of the Berlin wall in Berlin has become a gum wall:

[image]

([image source](https://www.steam-e.com/steam-e-berlin-wall/)).

The tourist attraction is mostly the Berlin wall and not the gum wall itself though.

Thanks to [Peter M](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/6188/peter-m) for helping me find it in a [comment](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175232/are-there-any-gum-wall-tourist-attractions-outside-the-us/175247#comment438933_175232).